# Mental model for working with linked list

Tags: java, algorithms, programming-practices, error-handling, linked-list

I have been doing some practice problems on [LinkedList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) but more than half of my time is spent on managing `null` pointer issue in my code, provided I have to keep track of `current`, `previous` and `runners` sometimes.

I need to know is there any way / model to deal with such issues?

Example:

```
public void deleteMid() {
    Node n = this;
    if (n.next == null) return;
    Node faster = this;
    Node prev = null;
    while (faster != null && faster.next != null) {
      prev = n;
      n = n.next;
      faster = faster.next.next;
    }
    prev.next = n.next;
  }
```

What are common pitfalls which should be avoided while mutating a list? are there any metal models which can help us to avoid those pitfalls?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do in this routine.  Perhaps you should consider adding explanatory comments, describing what the data structure is REALLY doing.  It LOOKS like a singly-linked list, but you can't delete an element from a singly-linked list unless you have a pointer to the preceding element, and there is no such pointer available from the sublist "to the right" of the element to be deleted.  So what's REALLY going on here?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm The preceding element is `prev`.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I have three pointers to keep track of the current, previous and lookahead pointers.

Comment: Is the list circular or not?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm no its not circular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your post, there are two questions here. One is how to build a mental model of a linked list. The other is how to deal with all of the checks for `null`.

If you want a simple model to think about linked lists, it would have to be this:

[image: train (locomotive and wagons)]

You have an important node which is the head, and from there you start going from node to node until you reach the end. It's like being inside a train. You go from wagon to wagon until you reach the last one. Adding and deleting nodes is like adding and removing wagons from the train. You have to connect the end of one node (or wagon) to the next node (or wagon).

In the linked list you have nodes that keep a reference to the next node. That's how you move through the list. The last node has no more nodes after it and you have to mark that somehow. In the train, when you see no more wagons then you are in the last wagon. In the linked list when you see a `null` reference you know there are no more nodes.

So `null` is important because it marks the last node, the node which links to no other nodes. But `null` is also a bit dangerous. Your code is general. You go from one `node` to `node.next`. And if `node.next` points to nowhere, if you do `node.next.next` you get a NullPointerException which crashes your program.

There is not much you can do if you want your code to work but to check for `null` in various places. You could separate the null checking and extract it in some method and have something like `if (hasNext(node)) {` or `if (node.hasNext()) {`, etc and move the `null` verification there. This way your code is more explicit in saying what it's doing instead of knowing for what all those checks for `null` are. But like I said, there is not much you can do. That's the nature of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, drawing diagrams is a big help. Also suitable names reduce the likelihood of errors... next and prev are understandable, but what does faster mean in your code?

Comment: One pointer iterates over nodes at position 0, 1, 2, ..., the faster one over nodes at 0, 2, 4, 6, ... When the faster one reaches the end of the linked list, the slower is in the middle of the list.

Answer (score -3):

You have every right to feel perplexed. The "null hack" obfuscates the core idea of many data structures. As you stated, the concept here is very simple: we can represent a linked list as a box-and-pointer diagram.

But how do we deal with all those pesky null pointers? If we accept the fact that a data structure is just another type, then we can take the "functional" view of a linked list:

```
type List a = Nil | Cons of a * List a
```

This definition is standard. A list is either the empty list, `Nil`, or the `Cons` (joining) of an element (of the correct type) with another list.

Note that there are *no pointers* in this definition. In particular, `Nil` is just a label: it is not the same as `null`, and it is most certainly not a pointer. Using `null` to represent an empty list is just a hack used by languages that lack sum types.

Comment: The answer is not helpful, you are arguing about treating empty lists as a "Nil" value instead of a "null" value, which does not help working with mutable nodes, in an imperative fashion. This is more a rant against null than anything else.

Comment: The OP says he is confused by null. I agree that null is confusing and offer an alternative that is (IMO) easier to think about. Considering the question is rather vague in what the OP specifically is looking for, I think this is quite helpful.

Comment: You could try re-writing this answer in a Java-like pseudocode. Someone confused by null is unlikely to understand your notation.

Comment: @Andres I could, but I don't see how that would help either. This isn't stack overflow, so just giving the OP the correct code is not really the point. ProgrammersSE, from what I understand, is related to software development practice in general. But to be honest I don't exactly know *what* the conceptual hurdle is that OP wants to overcome. I mean, I get it, writing a correct linked list implementation is surprisingly tricky. That's why every undergrad CS program has you doing it. But I don't know how to advice, so I just took a "shot in the dark" to provide an alternative.

Comment: @gardenhead Ok, ok, it was just an opinion. I wouldn't use `ML`/`Haskell`-like pseudocode which the OP is sure *not* to understand; as a general pedagogical rule, I'd approach any answer using the same kind of "language" (in the broadest sense of the word) that the person asking the question is using. But that's just me.

Comment: @AndresF. Considering the three downvotes I'd say most people would agree with you :D Man, I thought this was the reason I only visit Programmers and not SO. Also, despite coredump's objections, mutability does not require the use of null. I get bothered by the basic misconceptions people have about programming, but there's not much I can do over the internet.

Comment: @gardenhead I did not say that mutability requires the use of null. I am not against teaching algebraic datatypes. Nil and Cons are not much different operationally than a struct with a data and a next pointer. What makes lists easy in ML and a little bit harder in Java? Could OP try to write code differently to simplify it? If your answer addressed that and did not bash "null" gratuitously, that would a little more helpful.

Comment: @coredump To me they're very different conceptually, but YMMV. Also, I just realized that the OP's algorithm is actually the Tortoise and the Hare, contrary to what he named the function. Eh, this question isn't worth editing my answer for as it currently stands. Also, I don't believe there is such a thing as "gratuitous* null bashing. Null is a horrible mistake, and people should understand that it is a *flaw* in some languages, not something that is core to programming.